# How get I the Tomcat AJP-Connectors working?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, ajp

I want to access Tomcat through the Apache-webserver using connectors. I sticked to the documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html
I only modified it a little to match directory-structure used on my Debian-(Squeeze)-System.

So I added the following to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
# Load mod_jk module
# Update this path to match your modules location
#LoadModule    jk_module  libexec/mod_jk.so
# Declare the module for <IfModule directive> (remove this line on Apache 2.x)
#AddModule     mod_jk.c
# Where to find workers.properties
# Update this path to match your conf directory location (put workers.properties next to httpd.conf)
JkWorkersFile /etc/apache2/workers.properties
# Where to put jk shared memory
# Update this path to match your local state directory or logs directory
JkShmFile     /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.shm
# Where to put jk logs
# Update this path to match your logs directory location (put mod_jk.log next to access_log)
JkLogFile     /var/log/apache2/mod_jk.log
# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel    info
# Select the timestamp log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
# Send everything for context /examples to worker named worker1 (ajp13)
JkMount  /tomcat7/* worker1
```

I commented out the loading of the module, because that already happens, after I installed mod_jk through the package-system (libapache2-mod-jk).

My workers.properties look like this:

```
# Define 1 real worker using ajp13
worker.list=worker1
# Set properties for worker1 (ajp13)
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

Tomcat 7 is installed directly from archive from Apache, because it is not a package in Squeeze. Tomcat 7 is running and reachable under it's own port (8180, to not collide with tomcat6 from the package-system). As far as I understand, I should see now the tomcat-site with http://host/tomcat7/. But I get a 404 instead. What is wrong?

---

After quanta hinted to set the log-level to debug (thanks) I did that and found the following error-message in mod_jk.log: 'jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3585): missing uri map for 176.9.9.55:/tomcat7/'. I googled for that and found http://old.nabble.com/mod_jk%2C-missing-uri-map-td23984359.html

So the options set in httpd.conf weren't used in VirtualHosts. I added 'JkMountCopy On' to my VirtualHost - and got first a Tomcat 404 (instead of the httpd 404). Problem here, that he tries to access the exact same URI mounted, so in my case /tomcat7. I used instead the name of the webapp as mount and everything is fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that:

1. you type a trailing slash http://host/tomcat7**/**, not
   http://host/tomcat7.
2. you have a AJP 1.3 connector listen on port 8009 in `server.xml`:

   ```
   <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
   ```

If it still doesn't work, I suggest you turning on debug and take a look at `mod_jk.log`.

---

**EDIT:**

If you use:

```
JkMount  /tomcat7/* worker1
```

and access via http://host/tomcat7, I'm sure you will get the Apache 404 error.

You can specify `JkMount` in a Virtual Host section which you want:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  xx
    ServerAdmin xx

    JkMount /tomcat7 worker1
    JkMount /tomcat7/* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried with and without the slash and the server.xml contains the mentioned line. The mod_jk.log doesn't contain something interesting, only the message, that mod_jk was initialized.

Comment: Did you set `JkLogLevel` to `debug` and reload/restart Apache? Try this: `http://host/tomcat7/xx`. Post the entire content of `server.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution is to change `JkMount  /tomcat7* worker1` to `JkMount  /your-servlet-app* worker1`. You can have as many `JkMount` as you want.

For example, after adding `JkMount /manager* worker1`, you will be able to access `http://host/manager/html`

I figured out this problem after I tried both AJP and http. I had the following access log in my `/var/log/tomcat7/localhost_access_log.txt`

```
10.215.22.132 - - [04/Mar/2016:13:14:39 +0800] "GET /tomcat-demo/manager/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1009
10.215.22.132 - - [04/Mar/2016:13:26:05 +0800] "GET /tomcat-demo/manager/http/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1019
10.215.22.132 - - [04/Mar/2016:13:40:33 +0800] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
10.215.22.132 - - [04/Mar/2016:13:40:33 +0800] "GET /manager/html?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=E68B5F7E6E96D09C75A8D6854ECE9092 HTTP/1.1" 401 2474
10.215.22.132 - yz [04/Mar/2016:13:40:35 +0800] "GET /manager/html?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=E68B5F7E6E96D09C75A8D6854ECE9092 HTTP/1.1" 200 12405
```

The first two log lines were generated while I use AJP. The last three were generated while I use http to directly access tomcat. So apache is passing the whole URL to tomcat, instead of removing the jkmount prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Use mod_proxy_ajp or mod_proxy_http instead if you can:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html